# Не получается позиционировать виджеты

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Есть два файла.
Первый:

```
// main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';   
import 'colRow.dart'; 

void main() => runApp(App06Main());

class App06Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.grey[400],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20.0,
        ),
        child: buildColumn(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildTitleText() {
  return Text(
    "My Pet Shop",
    textScaleFactor: 3.0,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  );
}

Widget buildRoundedBox(
  String label, {
  double height = 88.0,
}) {
  return Container(
    height: height,
    width: 88.0,
    alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Text(
      label,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  );
}
```

Второй:
// colRow.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

Widget buildColumn(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      buildTitleText(),
      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
      _buildColumnWithinRow(),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _buildColumnWithinRow() {
  return Row(
    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      buildRoundedBox("Cat"),
      SizedBox(width: 20.0),
      buildRoundedBox("Dog"),
      SizedBox(width: 20.0),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildRoundedBox(
            "Big ox",
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          buildRoundedBox(
            "Small ox",
            height: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Вопрос такой.
В коде colRow.dart в виджете **_buildColumnWithinRow** никак не получается установить виджеты с текстами *"Big ox"* и *"Small ox"* (они находятся в Column) в *spaceBetween*. При подстановке в **MainAxisAlignment** *.spaceBetween* или *.spaceAround* или *.end* или других, эти два виджета позиционируются все время в центре.
Не могу понять, почему?

Answer (score 0):

> Не могу понять, почему?

Потому что его сжимает [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) выше. [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) сделает так, чтобы [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) занял всю доступную высоту.

```
Widget _buildColumnWithinRow() {
  return Expanded(
    child: Row(
//     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        buildRoundedBox("Cat"),
        SizedBox(width: 20.0),
        buildRoundedBox("Dog"),
        SizedBox(width: 20.0),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildRoundedBox(
              "Big ox",
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            buildRoundedBox(
              "Small ox",
              height: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Возможно я не правильно описал ситуацию.В предложенном Вами решении два виджета: "Big ox" и "Small ox" расположились вверху и внизу всего экрана. А мне надо, чтобы они раположились вверху и внизу родительского виджета Row (были бы ограничены родительским Row).

Comment: Ну сделайте вместо `Expanded`, `SizedBox` с заданной высотой. У вас изначально не правильная верстка, по этому такие проблемы и выходят.